# Inline expansion of variables in R

Tags: r

I'm confused with when a value is treated as a variable, and when as a string in R. In Ruby and Python, I'm used to a string always having to be quoted, and an unquoted string is always treated as a variable. Ie.

```
a["hello"] => a["hello"]
b = "hi"
a[b] => a["hi"]
```

But in R, this is not the case, for example

```
a$b < c(1,2,3)
```

b here is the value/name of the column, not the variable b.

```
c <- "b"
a$c => column not found (it's looking for column c, not b, which is the value of the variable c)
```

(I know that in this specific case I can use a[c], but there are many other cases. Such as `ggplot(a, aes(x=c))` - I want to plot the column that is the value of c, not with the name c)...

In other StackOverflow questions, I've seen things like quote, substitute etc mentioned.

My question is: Is there a general way of "expanding" a variable and making sure the value of the variable is used, instead of the name of the variable? Or is that just not how things are done in R?

Comment: I think `get`, mentioned below, is technically the most "general" solution. But the _correct_ answer will likely be different for different circumstances. e.g. See my comments below about the horrible-ness of not using `aes_string` in ggplot.

Comment: @joran I agree, but I don't think there is ever a *correct* way (or otherwise) to do this with the `$` operator.

Comment: You might find this helpful: https://github.com/hadley/devtools/wiki/Computing-on-the-language (it's still a work in progress)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example, `a$b` is syntatic sugar for `a[["b"]]`. That's a special feature of the `$` symbol when used with lists. The second form does what you expect - `a[[b]]` will return the element of `a` whose name == *the value* of the variable b, rather than the element whose name *is* "b".

Data frames are similar. For a data frame `a`, the `$` operator refers to the column names. So `a$b` is the same as `a[ , "b"]`. In this case, to refer to the column of `a` indicated by the *value* of `b`, use `a[, b]`.

Answer (score 3):

The reason that what you posted with respect to the `$` operator doesn't work is quite subtle and is in general quite different to most other situations in R where you can just use a function like `get` which was designed for that purpose. However, calling `a$b` is equivalent to calling

```
`$`(a , b)
```

This reminds us, that in R, *everything* is an object. `$` is a function and it takes two arguments. If we check the source code we can see that calling `a$c` and expecting R to evaluate `c` to `"b"` will *never* work, because in the source code it states:

```c
/* The $ subset operator.  
   We need to be sure to only evaluate the first argument.  
   The second will be a symbol that needs to be matched, not evaluated.  
*/
```

It achieves this using the following:

```c
if(isSymbol(nlist) )
SET_STRING_ELT(input, 0, PRINTNAME(nlist));
else if(isString(nlist) )
SET_STRING_ELT(input, 0, STRING_ELT(nlist, 0));
else {
errorcall(call,_("invalid subscript type '%s'"),
      type2char(TYPEOF(nlist)));
}
```

`nlist` is the argument you passed `do_subset_3` (the name of the C function `$` maps to), in this case `c`. It found that `c` was a symbol, so it replaces it with a string but does not evaluate it. If it was a string then it is passed as a string.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some links to help you understand the 'why's and 'when's of evaluation in R.  They may be enlightening, they may even help, if nothing else they will let you know that you are not alone:

http://developer.r-project.org/nonstandard-eval.pdf

http://journal.r-project.org/2009-1/RJournal_2009-1_Chambers.pdf

http://www.burns-stat.com/documents/presentations/inferno-ish-r/

In that last one, the most important piece is bullet point 2, then read through the whole set of slides.  I would probably start with the 3rd one, then the 1st 2.

These are less in the spirit of how to make a specific case work (as the other answers have done) and more in the spirit of what has lead to this state of affairs and why in some cases it makes sense to have standard nonstandard ways of accessing variables.  Hopefully understanding the why and when will help with the overall what to do.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the interesting bullet points. The Burns talk was, as always, entertaining. I must point out my answer centres around why what the OP posted *cannot* work, not how to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the variable named "b", use the get function in every case. This will substitute the value of b for get(b) wherever it is found.

Comment: Doesn't work for everything though.  `a <- "mpg"; mtcars$get(a)`

Comment: And I would never recommend the use of `get` in certain specific situations the OP mentions, like `ggplot`, where the correct solution is to use `aes_string`.

Comment: @joran I don't use ggplot2 too often.  I wish I knew about `aes_string` - a while back I resorted to using... `eval` and `parse` to do what I wanted...  Let the shunning commence...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to play around with expressions, you need to use quote(), substitute(), bquote(), and friends like you mentioned.

For example:

```
x <- quote(list(a = 1))
names(x) # [1] ""  "a"
names(x) <- c("", a)
x # list(foo = 1)
```

And:

```
c <- "foo"
bquote(ggplot(a, aes(x=.(c)))) # ggplot(a, aes(x = "foo"))
substitute(ggplot(a, aes(x=c)), list(c = "foo"))
```

Comment: Your `ggplot` example is clever, but terrible and should never be done.